# Saving form with m2m relationship not saving to database

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save a multiple select check box form using a m2m structure, but my values are not being saved to the database.

I have a State and Options. A State can have multiple Options and Options can have multiple states. In practice, I want to save multiple options for each state and then save the connections in the intermediate StateOption table. There is no error produced but when I check my database, nothing has been saved.

Also, if you see anything wrong with the way I set up my database structure, feel free to comment. I am new to databases and django.

models.py

```
class Option(models.Model):
    relevantdisease = models.ForeignKey(Disease)
    option = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class State(models.Model):
   state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   relevantdisease = models.ForeignKey(Disease)
   relevantoption = models.ManyToManyField(Option, blank=True, through='StateOption')

#intermediate table may not be needed
class StateOption(models.Model):
   state_table = models.ForeignKey(State)
   option_table = models.ForeignKey(Option)
```

forms.py

```
class StateOptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    option_choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Option.objects.all(), required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

    class Meta:
       model = State #StateOption if I use the intermediate table
       exclude = ['state_table', 'option_table']
```

views.py

```
def stateoption(request, disease_id, state_id):

    state = get_object_or_404(State, pk=state_id)
    disease = get_object_or_404(Disease, pk=disease_id)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = StateOptionForm(request.POST, instance=state)

        if form.is_valid():
           profile = form.save(commit=False)
           profile.user = request.user
           profile.save()    #this and the line below is probably where the problem is
           form.save_m2m()   


           #stateoption = StateOption.objects.create(state_table=state, option_table=profile)   <--produces an error saying that the instance needs to be Option

           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('success'))

    else:
        form = StateOptionForm(instance=state)


    context = {'state': state, 'disease':disease, 'option': form }
    return render(request, "stateoption.html", context)
```

**Update**
An intermediate table is probably not needed for this use case, but it will be needed as I add more complexity to this problem. Is there a way to save this form to the database with an intermediate table?

Comment: Well, that StateOption model isn't needed. Unless I'm missing something, the ORM should create the join table for you.

Comment: you're right. If i get rid of StateOption and use model = State in my StateOptionForm, the form still does not save in the tables ORM created for me. I only created an intermediate table so that it cuts down on the new tables created from 2 to 1. Any ideas on why it does not save?

Comment: Edit your code above and remove the StateOption model and then let's have a look.

Comment: done. edits are above

Comment: So it looks like it was the exclude parameter in my forms.py. I have to use 'relevantoption' otherwise the values do not get saved. But then there is no reason to use my form since 'relevantdisease' will be a multiselect. Is there any way I can still use my form?

Comment: Are you sure you're going to need an intermediate table? The tables should ideally represent models. If there are some data that need to be in the join table, then I would suspect some issues with the class design.

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. I'm pretty new to database design and django. I did post another question yesterday to see if I needed an intermediate table. If you have an input, your advice would be appreciate mate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368755/database-structure-design-for-m2m-relationship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve it by changing:

```
class StateOptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    option_choices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Option.objects.all(), required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)

to class StateOptionForm(forms.ModelForm):
    relevantoption = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Option.objects.all(), required=False, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

so that it matches my model.